# RxJava analog for Handler::removeMessages

Tags: java, android, rx-java, autocompletetextview

Before I've started to learn RxJava I made a DelayAutoCompleteTextView with a `Handler`, that handled TextChanged event. Now I rewrite code, to use Rx. But I can't make same behavior as I had before.

Code with `Handler`

```
@Override
protected void performFiltering(CharSequence text, int keyCode) {
    // remove pending query, because we have new one
    mHandler.removeMessages(MESSAGE_TEXT_CHANGED);

    // send with delay, to prevent big amount of network requests 
    // by removing unnecessary ones       
    mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(mHandler
            .obtainMessage(MESSAGE_TEXT_CHANGED, text), mAutoCompleteDelay);
}
```

My code with RxJava:

```
getTextChangedObservable(searchView) // onNext(str) in onQueryTextChanged 
                    // poor copy of old implementation
                    .throttleLast(750, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) 
                    .distinctUntilChanged() // prevent duplicates
                    ... // process
```

Thanks,
Anton

Comment: looks like you are looking for `debounce`

Comment: @VladimirMironov write an answer, I'll accept this, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code, looks like you are looking for debounce operator:

```
getTextChangedObservable(searchView)
    .debounce(750, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .subscribe(query -> {
        Log.d("Search", "Query " + query);
    });
```